# Ansible iterate stat results and create directories

Tags: ansible

> fatal: [172.24.66.221]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 've_exists.stat.exists == False' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ve_exists.stat.exists == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_47__tomcat_debug/test.yml': line 95, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: Create the directory\n        ^ here\n"}
>   fatal: [172.24.66.173]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 've_exists.stat.exists == False' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ve_exists.stat.exists == False): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stat'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_47__tomcat_debug/test.yml': line 95, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n      - name: Create the directory\n        ^ here\n"}

```
- name: Run the tasks inside the block
    block:
      - name: check the directory if already exist
        stat:
          path: /vtxnfs/{{ item }}
        with_items:
          - "vera_repository"
        register: ve_exists

      - name: Create the directory
        file:
          path: /vtxnfs/{{ item }}
          state: directory
          owner: "{{ user }}"
          group: "{{ user }}"
          mode: "0755"
        with_items:
          - "vera_repository"
        when: ve_exists.stat.exists == False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registered variable *`ve_exists`* contains the list of *`results`* because the module *`stat`* is running in the loop *`with_items`*. It is possible to loop *`ve_exists.results`* and create missing directories.

```
- name: Create the directory
  file:
    path: "/vtxnfs/{{ item.item }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ user }}"
    group: "{{ user }}"
    mode: "0755"
  loop: "{{ ve_exists.results }}"
  when: not item.stat.exists
```

---

Hint. Take a look at `ve_exists`

```
- debug:
    var: ve_exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will check the dir presence.

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  - name: Ansible check directory.
    stat:
    path: /project/devops/test
    register: my_folder
  - name: "echo if directory already existed"
    debug:
    msg: "the test directory is already existed"
    when: my_folder.stat.exists
  - name: "Ansible Create directory if not exists"
    file:
    path: /project/devops/test
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    group: root
    owner: root
    when: my_folder.stat.exists == false